# Android Smart Banner -- Manifest for Native App Install Complains About Missing Service Workers

Tags: android, web, mobile, android-manifest

I've read Google's documentation, googled around and looked through Stack Overflow, but haven't found any answers to this problem.

I need an Android Smart Banner to install a native app for the web site, and so (as per Google's instructions) have created the following manifest (details stubbed out for privacy reasons):

```
{
  "short_name": "ShortName",
  "name": "Longer App Name",
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "icons": [
    {
         "src": "icon.png",
         "type": "image/png",
         "sizes": "144x144"
     }
  ],
  "prefer_related_applications": true,
  "related_applications": [
    {
         "platform": "play",
         "id": "com.app.name"
    }
  ]
}
```

Since this is a native app, it doesn't require any service workers, [according to Google's guidelines](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/). However, when I open the site and try to add to the home screen (via the developer console), I keep getting the following error:

> Site cannot be installed: no matching service worker detected.  You
>   may need to reload the page, or check that the service worker for the
>   current page also controls the start URL from the manifest.

Do you know why this is happening?  It would seem that this things this isn't a native app install, but why would it think that?

I noticed a few suspicious things from the get go, like the fact that it complained about me not having start_url and display, even though the guidelines don't mention it as necessary for a native app.

Could you tell me what I did wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Reading [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/) i can only see some differences that i will put here so you can check:

- Png Icon size should be 192x192
- I would remove "start_url" and "display"
- Be visited by the user twice, over two separate days during the course of two weeks. (This could be important also)

Answer (score 0):

The service worker is a warning only for PWAs. For native applications, this can be ignored.

There is one missing criteria from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/native#criteria): multiple different icon sizes are required. Those sizes are `36x36`, `48x48`, `72x72`, `96x96`, `144x144`, `192x192`.

Here's an example:

```
{
  "name": "App Name",
  "short_name": "App Name Install Banner Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icon-0-75x.png",
      "sizes": "36x36",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icon-1x.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icon-1-5x.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icon-2x.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icon-3x.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icon-4x.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "prefer_related_applications": true,
  "related_applications": [
    {
      "platform": "play",
      "id": "com.google.samples.apps.iosched",
      "url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.samples.apps.iosched"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone"
}
```

As a reminder:

1. Enable this flag in chrome chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks
2. Login to Google Play on your Android device or emulator (make sure the emulator has the play store)
3. The app should not already be installed on the device
4. Follow the [requirements listed at the top here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/native#criteria)
5. Inspect the sources tab in your browser to see if the manifest is served correctly and remember to check the console for any errors (warnings are fine)